# Change color depending on background image

Tags: javascript, css, colors, background, background-color

So I have this problem, I have a menu with links in it and a picture that follows the curosor and go behind the links. But when the image goes behind the links the links are not visible enough due to their color.

Here is the video of the problem: [video](https://youtu.be/UXc9SOHRNO4)

So I wonder if there is something that can do the job, like a `backdrop-filter: invert(100%);` but just fot the text.

I already looked at some questions and they all say to use `mix-blend-mode: difference;` but that didn't work for me.

```js
let links = document.getElementsByClassName('navigation-links');

//making the nav appears
document.getElementsByClassName('burger')[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].style.cssText = "transform: scaleX(1);";

  let delay = 0;
  setTimeout(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      links[i].style.cssText = `transition-delay: ${delay}s; transform: skewY(0deg); opacity: 1;`;
      delay += 0.15;
    }
  }, 1250);
});

document.getElementsByClassName('x')[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
  let delay = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].style.cssText = `transition-delay: ${delay}s; transform: skewY(10deg); opacity: 0;`;
    delay += 0.15;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].style.cssText = "transform: scaleX(0);";
    console.log((0.15 * links.length) * 10, links.length);
  }, (150 * links.length) + 150);
});

//creating the picture chang animation
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    let catergoryIndex = this.index;
  });
}

//making the pictures follow the cursor
//https://www.superhi.com/video/smooth-movements-with-javascript

const image = document.getElementsByClassName("link-image-container")[0];

let mouseX = 0;
let mouseY = 0;

let imageX = 0;
let imageY = 0;

let speed = 0.25;


function movePicture() {

  let distX = mouseX - imageX;
  let distY = mouseY - imageY;


  imageX = imageX + (distX * speed);
  imageY = imageY + (distY * speed);

  let centerX = Math.max(Math.min(imageX - (image.offsetWidth / 2), window.innerWidth - image.offsetWidth), 0);
  let centerY = Math.max(Math.min(imageY - (image.offsetHeight / 2), window.innerHeight - image.offsetHeight), 0);

  image.style.left = `${centerX}px`;
  image.style.top = `${centerY}px`;

  requestAnimationFrame(movePicture);
}
movePicture();

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  mouseX = event.pageX;
  mouseY = event.pageY;
});
```

```css
.burger,
.x {
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 1%;
  right: 1%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scaleX(1.25);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.25);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(1.25);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(1.25);
  -o-transform: scaleX(1.25);
  animation: fadeIn .25s 2.5s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn .25s 2.5s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.x {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  top: calc(50% - 24px);
  right: 1%;
  transform: none;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
  -o-transform: none;
  animation: none;
  -webkit-animation: none;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  transform-origin: center right;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #fff;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: transform ease-in-out 1.25s;
  -webkit-transition: transform ease-in-out 1.25s;
  -moz-transition: transform ease-in-out 1.25s;
  -ms-transition: transform ease-in-out 1.25s;
  -o-transition: transform ease-in-out 1.25s;
}

.links-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation-links {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: playfair;
  text-align: center;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 39px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1% 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: 1s ease;
  -o-transition: 1s ease;
  color: #000;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: skewY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(0deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(0deg);
}

.navigation-links:hover {
  font-family: playfair-italic;
}

.link-image-container {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 55vh;
  transition: 0.15s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.15s;
  -moz-transition: 0.15s;
  -ms-transition: 0.15s;
  -o-transition: 0.15s;
}

.link-image-container img {
  pointer-events: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.transition-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="./assets/svg/x.svg" alt="x icon" class="x">
  <div class="links-container">
    <a index="0" class="navigation-links" href="">Link</a>
    <a index="1" class="navigation-links" href="">Link</a>
    <a index="2" class="navigation-links" href="">Link</a>
    <a index="3" class="navigation-links" href="">Link</a>
    <a index="4" class="navigation-links" href="">Link</a>
    <a index="5" class="navigation-links" href="">Link</a>
    <a index="6" class="navigation-links" href="">Link</a>
  </div>
  <div class="link-image-container">
    <img src="./assets/pictures/nature/photo_1.jpg" alt="link image example" class="link-image">
    <img src="./assets/pictures/night/photo_1.jpg" alt="link image example" class="transition-image">
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please show us your code as a snippet in your question. Especially we need to see how you tried mix blend mode.

Comment: I updated my code, see the attached snippet :-)

Comment: How didn't that work for you? It has some effect of changing the color

Comment: Well I don't know if its normal but I had to change my color to #fff (same as the background) to make it work. So now the color change perfectly, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your navigation-links class

```
.navigation-links{
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
   padding:2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way was to add the `mix-blend-mode: difference;` but also to change the navigation-links color to white so same as the background.